# java.io.IOException: Error code 5: Access Denied at Gradle Sync

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle

So, I have this old code of mine that I need to update and when I downloaded (from Git) and tried to start it fails at the Gradle Sync, I have tried a few of the solutions of similar questions and it didn't work.

Its a Kotlin code in Android Studio.

The error Log:

```
java.io.IOException: Error code 5: Acceso denegado.
    at com.android.tools.idea.diagnostics.windows.WindowsDefenderRegistryStatusProvider.readExcludedPaths(WindowsDefenderRegistryStatusProvider.java:62)
    at com.android.tools.idea.diagnostics.windows.WindowsDefenderRegistryStatusProvider.getExcludedPaths(WindowsDefenderRegistryStatusProvider.java:49)
    at com.android.tools.idea.diagnostics.WindowsPerformanceHintsChecker.getExcludedPatterns(WindowsPerformanceHintsChecker.java:242)
    at com.android.tools.idea.diagnostics.WindowsPerformanceHintsChecker.checkWindowsDefender(WindowsPerformanceHintsChecker.java:128)
    at com.android.tools.idea.diagnostics.WindowsPerformanceHintsChecker.access$000(WindowsPerformanceHintsChecker.java:65)
    at com.android.tools.idea.diagnostics.WindowsPerformanceHintsChecker$1.lambda$projectOpened$0(WindowsPerformanceHintsChecker.java:91)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:265)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Win32Exception: Acceso denegado.
    at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32Util.registryGetValues(Advapi32Util.java:2236)
    at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32Util.registryGetValues(Advapi32Util.java:2215)
    at com.android.tools.idea.diagnostics.windows.WindowsDefenderRegistryStatusProvider.readExcludedPaths(WindowsDefenderRegistryStatusProvider.java:57)
    ... 15 more
```

Its my first question on this site so I don't know how to upload the full log.

Comment: If the code is safe, have you tried disabling Windows Defender?

Comment: I disabled the real time defense and added exceptions to the project and still the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried running Android Studio with admin rights?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230369509

Comment: Upgrading my Android Studio to the Canary build worked, the solution was on the link @plplmax gave. Don't know how to mark the answer as the right one, if someone tells me how to do it i will do.

Comment: You can answer the question yourself and mark your answer as accepted